# Query ElasticSearch for an item by id, using its geo points to gather near-by results in a single request

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have an index of events, each event has an id and can contain multiple locations:

```
  id: {
    type: 'keyword'
  },
  locations: {
    type: 'geo_point'
  },
  title: {
    type: 'text'
  },
  etc...
```

Given an Id, I can query ElasticSearch and get a list of locations.

For each location I can then make a geo query and collect more events close by within an area.

Is there a form of query I could use to make a single round trip, maybe using aggregations?

Basically I would submit an id and get a collection of near by ids.

Still fairly new with ES so some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Unless you employ [scripted metric aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html), which, depending on your index size, could time out and probably won't scale.

Now, many-to-many comparisons are generally difficult to compute so it'd be best to perhaps average the list of geo points (via a centroid / a center of mass, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61162868/8160318)) and store that average in a new `geo_point` field (let's call it `anchor`). That way, you'll compare a static reference point to other points instead of performing two nested `for` loops trying to determine the closes pairs.

Once you've retrieved the coordinates of the doc in question, you can group your documents by their `id`s, exclude "self", and order the buckets by the result of the [`arcDistance` function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-index-fielddata.html#painless-api-reference-shared-ScriptDocValues-GeoPoints):

```json
POST geoindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nearby_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 5,
        "exclude": "0", 
        "order": {
          "geo_distance": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "min": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['anchor'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon)",
              "params": {
                "lat": 40.7388,
                "lon": -73.9982
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note that the `arcDistance` method accepts `lat, long` as parameters (in that order) and returns results in meters.*

Comment: Thank you for the pointers! Looking at scripted metric aggregations, I'm dealing with ~200K items with each ~5 locations. I understand that scale is relative but in general would you consider using it in such case? What would you consider an index too large?

Comment: You're welcome! ~200K should be just fine. In my own experience, things start to slow down around 3-5M, depending on the configuration and loads of other variables. Here's a list of [my answers regarding `scripted_metrics`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a8160318%20scripted_metric&searchOn=3), hope some of them help you get started :)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!